# fetch data async right after save and reload the component

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm retrieving data from an API, right now there are only two endpoints, one for adding users and other one for get the users added. The users are added using a button and its textbox.

```
  let [showAlert, setAlertState] = useState(false);
  let [twitterAccount, setTwitterAcount] = useState("Twitter Account here");
  let [dataInfo, setDataInfo] = useState([]);

  const getCurrentSpiedUsers = async () => {
    fetch("https://localhost:7021/GetCurrentSpiedUsers")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {setDataInfo(res)});
  }
  
  useEffect(function () {
    getCurrentSpiedUsers();
  }, []);
```

This part works as expected, the first time I enter into the website it loads data from the API.

This one is the other method for adding users.

```js
  const addTwitterAccount = (account) => {
    fetch(`https://localhost:7021/AddTwitterAccount?account=${account}`, {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        }
    )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => { });
  }
```

and this is the function inside of the `onClick` event button.

```js
  const activeAlert = () => {
    addTwitterAccount(twitterAccount);
    getCurrentSpiedUsers();
    setAlertState(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlertState(false);
    }, 5000);
  };
```

but this is not working as expected, once I click the button I add the account correctly, but can't reload the component using the `getCurrentSpiedUsers();` function. I noticed that when I click twice, I can get the last one but not the actual one, so I assume it's because the code it's executed faster than my function is retrieving the data from the API.

I tried using `async`/`await` for both methods, but the result is always the same. What can I do?

Updated with the server-side:

`AddTwitterAcccount` endpoint:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AddTwitterAccount : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ISpiedAccounts _spiedAccounts;

    public AddTwitterAccount(ISpiedAccounts spiedAccounts)
    {
        _spiedAccounts = spiedAccounts;
    }
    
    [HttpPost(Name = "AddTwitterAccount")]
    public void AddAccount([FromQuery] string account)
    {
        _spiedAccounts.AddTwitterAccount(account);
    }
}
```

`SpiedAccounts` class:

```
public interface ISpiedAccounts
{
    public void AddTwitterAccount(string accountName);
    public List<TwitterAccount> GetTwitterAccounts();
}


public class SpiedAccounts : ISpiedAccounts
{
    
    private List<TwitterAccount> accounts = new();
    private ResponseMessage _responseMessage;

    public void AddTwitterAccount(string accountName)
    {
        if (accounts.Any(account => account.ScreenName == accountName))
        {
            _responseMessage = ResponseMessage.UserExists;
            return;
        }
        
        int maxUsersSpied = 5;
        if (accounts.Count <= maxUsersSpied)
        {
            accounts.Add(new TwitterAccount
            {
                ScreenName = accountName
            });

            _responseMessage = ResponseMessage.Added;
            return;
        }
        
        _responseMessage = ResponseMessage.LimitUsersExceeded;
    }

    public string GetResponseMessage()
    {
        return _responseMessage switch
        {
            ResponseMessage.Added 
                => "The account was added correctly.",
            ResponseMessage.LimitUsersExceeded 
                => "Only can be spied 6 accounts at the time. Please, wait for one of them to be free.",
            ResponseMessage.UserExists 
                => "This account is currently being spied.",
            _ 
                => string.Empty
        };
    }
    
    public List<TwitterAccount> GetTwitterAccounts()
        => accounts;
}

public enum ResponseMessage
{
    Added,
    LimitUsersExceeded,
    UserExists
}
```

Comment: since they are both async calls, you need to chain them one after another. `call1.then(call2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a race condition between the WRITE (`addTwitterAccount`) and the READ (`getCurrentSpiedUsers`).

In other words, when you call `addTwitterAccount()` it will request the addition of a new twitter account, but **nothing guarantees** such operation has been completed (aka the account has been added) before `getCurrentSpiedUsers()` reads info from the datasource.

In fact, given you don't await for `addTwitterAccount()`, `getCurrentSpiedUsers()` will likely never bring the new account in its results.

### What to do?

First, await for the result of the `POST` (`addTwitterAccount()`) before proceeding to the `GET` (`addTwitterAccount()`):

```js
 const activeAlert = async () => {           // added async here
    await addTwitterAccount(twitterAccount); // added await here
    getCurrentSpiedUsers();
    ...
```

For that to work, make sure the `addTwitterAccount()` returns the `Promise`:

```js
  const addTwitterAccount = (account) => {
    return fetch(`https://loca......ount?account=${account}`, {  // added return
```

Second, edit the (server-side) endpoint at `https://localhost:7021/AddTwitterAccount` to guarantee** it only returns after the account has been completely added.

** <sub>There are other alternatives to this. You can make this endpoint be async, but you would need to use other tactics to know the user has been added. But all these other tactics would involve way more work, and you likely don't need the scalability they would provide you at the moment. Example tactics: WebSockets, SSE, long-polling. Making the endpoint block until the account is created, as I suggested above, is likely the more cost-effective solution at this point.</sub>

Comment: I did try using async/await just like this, but the result is the same, I assume it could be caused by what you said but I'm not sure due to the class itself is simple, it's only adding a object to a list, nothing else. I'm not sure if you're familiar with C# but unfortunately my API is made on C#, I've updated my post in case it helps, thanks!

Comment: Does `private List<TwitterAccount> accounts = new();` create a thread-safe list? The `await` at the call to `addTwitterAccount()` is mandatory. Do it like this: place a `debugger;` line just after that and run your app (with dev tools open) and click your button. This should stop the app at the breakpoint. Now wait a couple of seconds and hit continue. Does this work?

Comment: Hi again, thanks! after debugging it yeah it works, but I'm trying right now using async/await and still is not working. (I had to make the function `addTwitterAccount()` async so I can use the `await` keyword), but still the same result. so does it mean there's something wrong with the server-side? Also `Lists` are not thread-safe. Could because of that? And why? Kinda new in this, sorry! :)

Comment: Ah, of course, your `addTwitterAccount()` must `return` the result from fetch, like this: `const addTwitterAccount = (account) => {
    return fetch(\`https:\`...`. I edited the answer to point this out

Answer (score -1):

you can't use multiple setState in one event it will do only the first one,
my suggestion is to use only one state with an object that contains your data